Gunicorn with muiltple works but shared memory
My Falcon + Gunicorn backend accesses a relational database holding data that forms a graph – a table with nodes and a table with edges. Since the graph is not large (a couple of hundred nodes and edges) I load the data once a startup into a Networkx DiGraph and keep it in memory. Thus, when I request the graph data

no constant access to the database is required which sounds good w.r.t. performance
easy use of built-in methods provided by NetworkX to extract different types of subgraphs

Question 1: Is this good practice or are there any (principle) downsides to this approach (beyond my problem below)?
While the graph is not highly dynamic – no "normal" API endpoint edits the graph – it might grow over time in the database. I therefore created an additional endpoint /graph/reload that when called simply reloads the graph into memory (i.e., the NetworkX DiGraph object). So anytime there is indeed a change to the database, I call this endpoint.
In principle, this seems to work. However, the problem now is when I run the server using Gunicorn and multiple workers. When I call /graph/reload then this is done only for one worker instance; the others still use the old graph.
Question 2: What is the best way to handle this?
Of course, I could always access the database for each request. I still would be curious if this can be done with keeping the graph in memory

If you can afford having multiple database copies in memory for each worker, I think that your approach is not unreasonable.
If you wish to continue the same pattern that you started with, you can communicate the reload event to all the workers using the stdlib's multiprocessing primitives such as multiprocessing.Condition:

Initialize the database before forking worker processes.
Create a shared condition variable before forking worker processes.
After forking worker processes, start a thread in each one listening to changes via the condition variable that is shared between the processes.
Upon receiving a reload request, perform the reload from each worker thread.

I find using a custom Gunicorn application easier to control the forking and initialization of workers; a complete code example for your use case could look like:
import datetime
import json
import logging
import multiprocessing
import os
import pathlib
import random
import threading

import falcon
import gunicorn.app.base

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

DATA_SOURCE = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'data.json'


class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        # TODO: Fake data, actually load external resource.
        now = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
        self._data = {
            'created': now.isoformat(),
            'numbers': random.sample(range(100, 1000), 16),
        }
        self._cv = multiprocessing.Condition()

        with open(DATA_SOURCE, 'w') as fp:
            json.dump(self._data, fp, indent=4)

    def _reload(self):
        with open(DATA_SOURCE, 'r') as fp:
            self._data = json.load(fp)
        logging.info(f'Reloaded database (PID: {os.getpid()})')

    def start_reload_loop(self):
        def reload_loop():
            while True:
                with self._cv:
                    if self._cv.wait(timeout=3.0):
                        self._reload()

        thread = threading.Thread(target=reload_loop, daemon=True)
        thread.start()
        logging.info(f'Starting reload thread... (PID: {os.getpid()})')

    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        resp.media = self._data

    def on_post_reload(self, req, resp):
        with self._cv:
            self._cv.notify_all()
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_ACCEPTED


class PIDInfo:
    def process_response(self, req, resp, resource, req_succeeded):
        resp.set_header('X-Gunicorn-Worker', str(os.getpid()))


class ServerApplication(gunicorn.app.base.BaseApplication):
    db = Database()

    @classmethod
    def post_fork(cls, arbiter, worker):
        cls.db.start_reload_loop()

    def __init__(self):
        self.options = {
            'accesslog': '-',
            'bind': '127.0.0.1:8000',
            'post_fork': self.post_fork,
            'workers': 8,
        }

        self.application = app = falcon.App(middleware=[PIDInfo()])
        app.add_route('/database', self.db)
        app.add_route('/database/reload', self.db, suffix='reload')

        super().__init__()

    def load_config(self):
        config = {key: value for key, value in self.options.items()
                  if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None}
        for key, value in config.items():
            self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)

    def load(self):
        return self.application


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ServerApplication().run()

After starting the server app, you can access our fake database by sending an HTTP GET request to http://localhost:8000/database. The fake database is simulated by the data.json file in the same directory that is overwritten upon startup.
Edit the file, and perform an HTTP POST request to http://localhost:8000/database/reload. You should see the updated data in subsequent GET requests.
An alternative approach would be somehow storing your in-memory database in an mmap-ed memory that is initialized before forking the workers.
If you wanted simpler code that avoids inter-process synchronization, you could also cache the data in memory for a certain time, and if needed, have a separate source of truth for indicating reload (i.e., purge cache instead of using it).

thanks! For the time being I go with the "classic" approach and fetching the data from database for each API request, with some basic caching on the client side. It's just a prototype at the moment anyway.
